# Multi-Process/Multi-Threaded C Server reads null-string from socket

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, recv, listen

I'm working on a Server in C using a Multi-Process / Multi-Threaded architecture. At the start I've a main process that forks 10 different processes. Each process creates a pool of threads. Each process is, also, the controller of its pool (creates new thread / extends the pool when needed).
The processes also listen on the socket (whose access is controlled by the main process with an unnamed semaphore in a shared memory area) and pass the socket file descriptor to one of the thread in their pool when a connection is acquired. The chosen thread (which is awakened by a `pthread_cond_signal`) reads from the socket with a `recv` using the option `MSG_DONTWAIT`.

```
ssize_t readn, writen;  
size_t nleft;
char *buff;
buff = malloc(sizeof(char) * BUFF_SIZE);
if (buff == NULL) {
    perror("malloc");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
char *ptr = buff;
/*if (fcntl(connsd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK) == -1) {       // set to non-blocking
    perror("fcntl");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}*/
errno = 0;
nleft = BUFF_SIZE;
while(nleft > 0) {
    if ((readn = recv(connsd, ptr, nleft, MSG_DONTWAIT)) < 0) {
        if (errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK) {
            *ptr = '\0';
            break;
        }
        else if (errno == EINTR) 
            readn = 0;
        else {
            perror("read");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
    else if (readn == 0) 
        break;

    if (buff[strlen(buff)-1] == '\0') {
        break;
    }

    nleft -= readn;
    ptr += readn;
}
```

The problem is that sometimes, when I try to connect to the server using Chrome (or Firefox) 3 threads seems to receive the HTTP Request but each one of them simply closes the connection because of this portion of code.

```
if (buff[strlen(buff)-1] != '\0') {
    printf("%s\n",buff);
    fflush(stdout);
    buff[strlen(buff)-1] = '\0';
}
errno = 0;
if (strlen(buff) < 1) {
    perror("No string");
    if (shutdown(connsd,SHUT_RDWR) < 0) {
        perror("shutdown");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if (close(connsd) < 0) {
        perror("close");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Other times we have 3 threads with different behaviours: one of them receives and reads from the socket the first HTTP Request (GET / HTTP/1.1). The second one is empty (request received (because it is awakened (?)) no string read). The third one receives and reads another HTTP Request (GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1).

Where is the problem that cause these behaviours? I can add other portions of code if needed.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: This code:  `if (buff[strlen(buff)-1] == '\0')` will **never** work as you expect.  If the `strlen()` returns 4, whatever is at `buff[3]` can not be `'\0'` by the very definition of what the length of a string means.  And what happens if the length of the string is zero?

Comment: It seems like you're focusing in the wrong place.  If indeed "The problem is that sometimes, when I try to connect to the server using Chrome (or Firefox) 3 threads seems to receive the HTTP Request" then surely the place to start is determining why three separate threads are all trying to handle the same request, and fixing that.  You don't appear to have presented any of the code relevant to that.

Comment: They not handle the same request but three different ones. Maybe 2 of them are the same in the last case, bit in the first case i have 3 empty requests. I'm trying to understand why.